# U-net: TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'

Tags: python, tensorflow

i am working on segmentation of brain tumor dataset provided by BraTS challenge based on u-net. After defining the model at the stage of training an error occurred.

The error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-d745053f879c> in <module>()
      1 Folders = ReadDataset(PATH)
      2 TrainGenerator = MyGenerator(PATH)
----> 3 Model=unet()
      4 Model.fit_generator(TrainGenerator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=25)
      5 #for Index, Folder in enumerate(Folders):

<ipython-input-54-baecfef1ddd3> in unet(pretrained_weights, input_size)
     41     conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)
     42 
---> 43     model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)
     44 
     45     model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'
```

```
def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (240, 240,4)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', 
            kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', 
            kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)

    .
    .
    .


    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)

    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
                              metrics = ['accuracy'])


    return model
```

And the training code is:

```
Folders = ReadDataset(PATH)
TrainGenerator = MyGenerator(PATH)
Model=unet()
Model.fit_generator(TrainGenerator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=25)
Train, Test, Valid = Split(Folders, 0.8)
```

I am just trying to get some result as i am beginner in deep learning. Any help would be highly appreciated and i would be very grateful.

Comment: what is `Model` inside `unet`? And what is `Model` in `Model = unet()` ? Maby you have problem because you use the same name for two different elements ?

Comment: BTW: there is good rule - for variables use `lower_case_names` - ie. `model = unet()`, only for names of classes use `CamelCaseNames`. It helps to recognize class in code. See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: @furas Model is defined anywhere above. It is introduced here: `model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)`. I am confused. Thanks for the response and further help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much, guys, for the responses! This question was silly one; actually this was segmentation code based on Keras-TensorFlow and I was not importing these modules at the beginning of the code. I must say that it was my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Keras require you to use 'inputs' instead of 'input' as the name of the first input parameter for Model. Check if you can update your Keras version (current stable is 2.2.5) or try this line:

```
model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = conv10)
```

possibly:

```
model = Model(inputs = [inputs], outputs = [conv10])
```

Instead of:

```
model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, @mrkolarik. Indebted! I am running the code on Google Colab. The version should not be the issue I think so. The 'Model' is not defined somewhere above, it is introduced here, just at the end of defined function unet as:   'model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)'